# match() in javascript returns array with null strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to detect currency and extract digit from such strings as "10 dollars", "dollars 10", etc. I use String.prototype.match() and regex

`/((dollar|usd\$)\s*(\d+)|(\d+)\s*(dollar|usd\$))/i`

But match() returns me for "10 dollars"

```
["10 dollar", "10 dollar", undefined, undefined, "10", "dollar"]
```

and for "dollar 10"

```
["dollar 10", "dollar 10", "dollar", "10", undefined, undefined]
```

How I can avoid that situation and get predictable digit position ?

Comment: You may check which group matched.

Comment: Super simple `/(\d+)\ (dollar|usd)|(dollar|usd)\ (\d+)/gi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mark any group (things in `(parentheses)`) in a regex as "non-capturing" by adding `?:` after the left paren, as in `(?:non|capturing|group)`.

So if all you want is the digits, not the word "dollar" or "usd", you could do:

```
/(?:(?:dollar|usd\$)\s*(\d+)|(\d+)\s*(?:dollar|usd\$))/i
```

That will give you `["dollar 10", undefined, "10"]` for "10 dollars". From there, just do:

```
var matches = myString.match(/(?:(?:dollar|usd\$)\s*(\d+)|(\d+)\s*(?:dollar|usd\$))/i);    
var amount = matches[2] || matches[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

You may check which group matched and then grab the necessary value.

I suggest simplifying the structure a bit by turning alternations to non-capturing groups and removing the outer group:

```
/(?:dollars?|usd\$)\s*(\d+)|(\d+)\s*(?:dollars?|usd\$)/i
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jmb8lE/1)

A demo  test:

```js
var re = /(?:dollars?|usd\$)\s*(\d+)|(\d+)\s*(?:dollars?|usd\$)/i;
var strs = ["10 dollars", "dollars 30"];
for(var t of strs) {
  var m = t.match(re);
  if (m && m[2]) 
    console.log(m[2]);
  else if (m) console.log(m[1]);
 
}
```